# How to force open tree folder in lwuit?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I  have used the tree component of lwuit and it is working fine.
Now i need to force open the tree folder/parent node on any keyevent. I could not find a way to force open the folder?

Any heads up will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the button representing the node you want and just invoke the `pressed()` method on it.

There used to be an issue requesting a more elegant approach to this in the LWUIT issue tracker but if we will do something on that it will only be fore [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/).